# How to identify the 8-bit checksum algorithm on this data

Tags: python, serial-port, checksum, crc

I have some data that passed over a RS232 connection, with a checksum at the end. I would like to know what the checksum function is. I've tried multiple variants of crc8 as well as simple XOR or addition, to no avail.

How can I identify the checksum function ?

Here is some data and checksums:

```
b'\x0f\xc8\x1c|\x00\x00d\xa2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'    -> 0x8a
b'\x0f\xc8?|\x00\x006\xa2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'       -> 0x95
b'\x0f\xc9\xc4^\x00\x00om\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'       -> 0x29
```

Comment: It's definitely not a CRC.

Comment: The first two are `0xff` minus the low eight bits of the sum of the message bytes. The third one is not. Are you sure the third checksum is correct? (Should be `0x29`.)

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes it is. It is definetely the solution you're suggesting. How did you find that ? I'll be happy to accept and upvote if you post an answer :) (possibly with the method/reasoning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with the update to the question with a corrected check value, it appears that they are `0xff` minus the low eight bits of the sum of the message bytes.

This was found by simply adding the message bytes and the check value and seeing that in each case, the low eight bits were `0xff`. In fact, that is the easiest way to check the check value.